# $\frac{dy/dt}{dx/dt} \text{ at } t = a \text{ or } \lim_{t \to a} \frac{dy/dt}{dx/dt} \text{?}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, parametric

Take an example of parametric equation:

\begin{cases}
x = t^3\\
y = t^6
\end{cases}

Obviously the formula $\displaystyle \left. \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy/dt}{dx/dt} \right.$ does not work at $t=0 \Big(\displaystyle \frac{dy/dt}{dx/dt} = \frac{0}{0}\Big)$.

But at $t = 0 \text{, } (x, y) = (0, 0)$, and $\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dx} = 0.$

Answer (score 1):

The derivative is not defined at x=0, but the derivative exists in terms of a limit. The point (0,0) is what's called a "cusp". It is a point where the particle momentarily comes to a standstill and then picks up speed again.

Comment: When you eliminate t from the parametric equations, sure, the derivative exists. But if only the parametric equations are to be considered, then no. dy/dt = dx/dt = 0 for t=0, hence dy/dx is an indeterminate form. As a limit t approaches zero, the derivative exist, but for t=0 it does not. Anytime when a particle has come to a standstill in terms of its speed for some particular t value, there is momentarily no direction and thus no derivative. In short, you can't have a derivative when partial derivatives are zero for the same t-value

Comment: There's no cusp. It's basically y = x^2.

Comment: True, it is not a cusp and it is a parabola. If I were to draw a tangent, it certainly would be the x-axis. My point was that if both dy/dt and dx/dt are zero for the same value, it is not proper to say that dy/dx exists since in parametric form dy/dx is defined as dy/dt over dx/dt. Once you eliminate t, it becomes a different story. I certainly won't dispute that y=x^2 has an existing derivative at the Origin...

Comment: PS, if you get a chance, take a course in Differential Equations. Tough course, but this kind of stuff is addressed in great detail.